# list view animation

Tags: android

I have a list view with custom adapter. I'm trying to implement following
when a item in the list is clicked, only that item is expanded and show some info.
when it is clicked again, it goes back to the first state. can any one suggest a
way to achieve this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ExpandableListView.

It can help you.

ExpandableListView can expanded and back to the first state.

Also, you can custom inner layout.(some info)

please use it.